# Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in Open Restaurant

Tags: 7, theming

I installed [Open Restaurant](https://www.drupal.org/project/restaurant) based on Drupal 7.x.

As soon as I insert any menu item into create categories, I get this warning:

> Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in sizzle_preprocess_views_view__content__menus__all_menus() (line 69 of /web/htdocs/xxxxxxxxxxx/home/profiles/restaurant/themes/sizzle/includes/menu.inc).

I checked the line and I got this code:

```
// Render the category and add it to template.
$variables['term'] = drupal_render(taxonomy_term_view($term, $view_mode));
```

I don't know how to improve this, in order to solve the issue.
Writing to the group that made Open Restaurant I didn't got any answer. Hence my post here.

Comment: Issues found in existing modules are offtopic here, but since you *are* trying to fix it yourself, you are in gray area... I posted an answer, but make sure it'll be in their issue queue, too, OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drupal_render` takes reference. `taxonomy_term_view($term, $view_mode)` is not a variable, so you shouldn't use it in places where reference is needed - because if something takes reference, it will try to update what it got, and it's impossible with a function. So to fix this, you need to create variable, then store result of `taxonomy_term_view` in it, and pass that variable to `drupal_render`.

Then, create patch file nd post it in their issue queue for everybody to see.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I did in this way, the error didn't show up anylogner and I got not any issue with the template.

`-         $variables['term'] = drupal_render(taxonomy_term_view($term, $view_mode));
+   $just_variable = taxonomy_term_view($term, $view_mode);
+   $variables['term'] = drupal_render($just_variable);`